# styled-components: worried about FOUC

Tags: reactjs, webpack, styled-components

I've been into the [styled-components](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components) package and I think the developer-friendliness is awesome!

However, I'm worried about 1 thing: **Flash Of Unstyled Content**.

Since in production, as well as in development, the styles get packaged with the javascript chunks; When a component is loaded, the styles are generated and appended (at the bottom of) the `<head>`.
This is inherently the same as how CSS Modules work.

Referring to a post of [surviveJS](https://survivejs.com/webpack/styling/separating-css/) I learned to use ExtractTextPlugin to create separate stylesheets (css files) during the production build step.

However, in `styled-components` CSS is just JS, so we can't use that technique (at least, I couldn't get it to work).

So before I start building my next project with styled-components, can someone take my worries away?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to have your UI flash - you need to send your styles from the server instead of rendering using JS. Fortunately, `styled-componnets` library supports server rendering API, even though it is not public at this moment.

You can pre-render your styles on a server, and inject into your initial html you send from the server, so it will contain CSS and UI won't flash.

As I mentioned, API is not public yet, but you can use it. There are multiple discussions about this on a Github, please, check: [this](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/124), [this](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/386) and  [more issues](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=server%20rendering&type=Issues). I guess public API should be ready in a v2 release.

So basically there are should be no issues with using `styled-components` to prevent flashing.

Comment: Good to know. Unfortunately server side rendering is not an option for this project

Answer (score 0):

SSR is coming in v2 which you can start using today. Here is an example of how to do it.

https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/blob/v2/example/ssr.js